# Why in C input requires memory location of variable instead of name of variable itself?

Tags: c, variables, memory, location, scanf

Is there any particular reason why while taking input C (scanf) prefers to take memory location of variable instead of the name of variable itself ?
I know its definition of scanf which mandates above ?
But is there any special reason ?
Like in c++ if u want to take input you'll write cin>>var;
But why not in ?
Is it something to keep language faster ?

Comment: Because C passes arguments by copy, without using pointer it cannot modify an object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because values to functions in C are passed *by value*. And, of course, being a compiled language names of variables don't exist at run-time, it's all addresses in memory at that point.

If you pass the variable directly, you just pass the value, which is what `printf()` needs:

```
int a = 32;
printf("a=%d\n", a);
```

but if you did the same with `scanf()', it would just get the integer value`32`, with no idea where it came from. Since the point of`scanf()` is to *change* the value of the caller's variable, you pass the address of the variable:

```
int a = 32;
scanf("%d", &a);
```

Then the code inside `scanf()` can write a new integer value at the given address, which causes the value to change in `a`.

Comment: I got your point and appreciate your response.
But my question is why to take memory location instead of variable name.
Like in c++ if u want to take input you'll write cin>>var;
But why not in ?
Is it something to keep language faster ?

Comment: @user2511623 C++ introduced references, which (to put it very crudely) are just syntax sugar for pointers. The underlying principle with references (what `cin>>` uses) is exactly the same as with pointers (what `scanf` uses). C did not have references, so the only option was pointers.

Comment: Thanks tom.
Is it one of the reason that makes c is faster than c++ and others?

Comment: @Harikesh No. Modern optimizing compilers are extremely complicated and speculations on what would be faster and why are useless.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the variable by reference to scanf() so that the scanf() can write the data at that address..

Comment: -1, `scanf()` certainly doesn't "write the address to the provided pointer".